# Is there a replacement for the clearaudit tool provided by ClearCase?

Tags: clearcase

I am looking for a way to find out all the clearcase elements used while building the application.My application is linux based and it uses combination of Makefiles,ant scripts and shell scripting for building,I am thinking on something similar to clearaudit so I don't have to modify my existing build scripts.

Any tip/tool/help would be appreciated ,Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, the answer is no: there is no (free) readily available tool to replace clearaudit.  Depending on what kind of data you're trying to collect, there are various ways to get the same data but it is platform dependent.

As VonC suggests, strace can be used on UNIX platforms to track read() calls.  On Linux in particular, inotify based tools linux [inotifywatch](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch) can be used.

On Windows, your options are much more complicated. The most straightforward programmatic solution is [ReadDirectoryChangesW](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4465cafb-f4ed-434f-89d8-c85ced6ffaa8/), but the way it works is *[broken by design](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2011/08/12/10195186.aspx)* but may be useful [in some situations](http://qualapps.blogspot.com/2010/05/understanding-readdirectorychangesw.html).

Commercially, ectool that ships with [ElectricCommander](https://electriccloud.zendesk.com/entries/229369-all-documents) appears to offer the same kind of functionality as a minor part of a larger feature-set.

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool called [Audited Objects](http://audited-objects.sourceforge.net/). It audits all open files (not only on VOB) and provides query tool to get required list of files (you can choose only read or only written or both) from the audit file.

You can give it a try and check if it suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a native way in ClearCase of emulating [clearaudit](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/clearaudit.htm) (like it is described in "[About clearaudit](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21146385)")

The only other way to try and extract that information would be using **[strace](http://linux.die.net/man/1/strace)**

> In the simplest case, `strace` runs the specified command until it exits.
>   It intercepts and records the system calls which are called by a process and the signals which are received by a process

```
strace -efile yourScript
```

That would list all accessed files during the execution of the script.
If you know where your ClearCase files are, you can extract from this list all the versioned files used.
But this is not a native ClearCase solution.